# public Youtube / Google API test account / channel

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, oauth2-playground

I'm trying to test my implementation for the Youtube Analytics API, but my own Google Accounts doesn't have any (advanced audience) data to provide.

Is there any public available test account (Youtube Channel), so i can check my requests (with useful response data)?